# Swift UIButton not appearing on screen

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a view in my tabbar controller where I would like to show a button. I create this button programmatically based of a condition, therefore I use the following code but nothing is appearing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if !Settings.getIsConnected() {
        notConnected()
    }
}

func notConnected() {
    let connectBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y, width: 200, height: 45))
    connectBtn.setTitle("Connect", forState: .Normal)
    connectBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressedConnect(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(connectBtn)

    print("Button created")
}

func pressedConnect(sender: UIButton!) {

}
```

I am clueless on what I am doing wrong. Anyone got suggestions? Cause it does print out "Button created" so it definitely runs the code inside the noConnected() method.

Comment: Try to add a background color to your UIButton, and and a tint color to its title

Comment: Thanks that was the problem! Somehow the title and button are all white

Comment: I saw a similar problem recently, I think that this is the default color when we create programmatically a UIButton

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a background color to your `UIButton` and add a tint color to the title. This will resolve the problem

Answer (score 4):

Try moving the code to `viewDidAppear` and see if the button is showing up.

The frame is not correctly set when in `viewDidLoad`. Use the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for the earliest possible time where the frame is correctly setup for a ViewController.

With this code change, you will need some additional logic for when your button should be added as a subview though.

Answer (score 1):

A programmatically created button may not show up because of more reasons, e.g:

- the tint color is not set
- the background color is not set
- the button is not added to the view hierarchy
- the button is hidden

In your case, you should change the tint color or the background color of your button.

E.g.:
Swift 4.2:

```
private lazy var connectButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Connect", comment: ""), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(connectButton)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-check the button *properties* in the storyboard that it is not ***hidden***.